# execvp system call problems

Tags: c, posix, execvp

I'm making a small shell to better understand C. I use the POSIX getline function to get a string and split it into tokens by the whitespace. But when I'm calling execvp() to make the system call, nothing happens.. If someone cal point to me where the issue I have, clearly I'm missing something probably small..(I didn't include the whole code so some curly brackets will be missing at the bottom, just ignore this sorry) Many thanks

```
        char *args[3];  // array for the command and arguments

        cmd = strtok(line, " ");            
        args[0] = cmd;              // put the first command in the array

        for(int i = 1; i < whitespace+1; ++i){

            cmd = strtok('\0', " \n");
            args[i] = cmd;              // fill the array of strings with the arguments
        }
        args[2] = '\0';    // assign last element to NULL


        pid = fork();

        if(pid != 0){        
            waitpid(-1, &stat, 0); 
        }
        else{

            char *const *test[1];
            test[0] = '\0';
            execvp("/bin/ls", test[0]);
            execvp(args[0], &args[1]);
```

Right at the end is where I'm having issues, I tried both versions of execvp seperately but neither work and I've been stuck on this issue for 2 days.. Any help appreciated thanks

Comment: Your `args[2] = '\0';` is an unorthodox (but legal) way of setting a null pointer.  It also limits your command to at most one file name.  The loop before it becomes a bit redundant.  You then have two `execvp()` calls; if the first succeeds, the second won't be executed.  The correct way to call `execvp()` is `execvp(args[0], args);`.  You should have error reporting code after the `execvp()` -- if it returns, it failed -- and should normally exit.

Comment: Note that `getline()` is a GNU extension, not specified by POSIX.  I only have your word that you're using it, though, as it does not appear in the code you presented.

Comment: How is a more orthodox way to set the null pointer. Thank you for the tip on the correct way to call execvp.

Comment: Do note that when `execvp()` works, it does not return, so it is rarely appropriate to call it twice in a row.  If it *does* return then an error has occurred, and you can get a handle on the nature of that error via the `errno` variable, perhaps by means of the `perror()` function.

Comment: "How is a more orthodox way to set the null pointer"? `args[2] = NULL;` If `NULL` isn't defined, include `<stddef.h>`

Comment: Sorry I dont actually call execvp twice.. I commented the one using arrays out and tested with the literal string to see if it was a problem with my array set up. Thank you for the NULL header file suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example of how to make `execvp` work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( void )
{
    char *test[2];              // declare an array of pointers
    test[0] = "/bin/ls";        // first arg is the path to the executable
    test[1] = NULL;             // NULL terminator indicates no additional args
    execvp( test[0], test );
}
```

Here's an explanation from the man page for `execvp`

> The first argument, by convention, should point to the file name
>   associated with the file being executed.  The array of pointers must
>   be terminated by a NULL pointer.